# PHP function returns wrong values

Tags: php, sql, function

I have this function

```
function getNick($uid)
{
    $sqli = "SELECT nick FROM users WHERE userid='".$uid."'";
    mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$sqli);
    $resulti = mysqli_query($con,$sqli);
    $rowi = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulti);   
    if($resulti->num_rows > 0) return $rowi["nick"];
    else return "(none)";
}
```

Basically it should return me nick based on user's id. Problem is that I only keep getting '(none)'. What is interesting I printed actual $sqli and copied it into phpMyAdmin and it worked as expected. I even tried to just print nick without IFs but I ended up with empty string. What might be the issue? Am I overlooking something? Thanks

Comment: Use this mysqli_num_rows()

Comment: It didn't work and problem has to be somewhere else as I had echo under mysqli_fetch_assoc and it was empty string.

Comment: Chk $con are u getting connection resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

function getNick($uid,$con)
{

    $sqli = "SELECT nick FROM users WHERE userid='".$uid."'";
    mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$sqli);
    $resulti = mysqli_query($con,$sqli);
    $rowi = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulti);   
    if($resulti->num_rows > 0) return $rowi["nick"];
    else return "(none)";
}

echo getNick(1,$con);
?>
```

**it works**

variable scope problem

use above method to pass connection in method or

use `$GLOBALS['con']` to access connection in method `getNick`